# How to take some action when an ASP session times out?

Tags: asp-classic, session-timeout

I want to take some server-side action when a (classic) ASP session times out, such as for example recording the event in a logfile. In Java I would add a SessionListener and write the log message from the sessionDestroyed() method. Is there an ASP equivalent of a SessionListener, and how would I use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classic ASP Session Timeout: Can I Perform Any Actions on Timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776631/classic-asp-session-timeout-can-i-perform-any-actions-on-timeout)

Comment: You can't write to files when the session is ended. As far as I know, you're limited to modifying Application variables e.g. `Application("test") = "a session has ended"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that can be fired in classic ASP when a session times out.

Recommend you run your session management semi manually, log all user sessions with their last updates to a database, run another ASP file on a cron (task scheduler) timer (every min) from the server or whereever that checks for sessions that are over the time out (session) time and fire your actions from there.

Log the session.sessionID from the users in the database table, on each page load for the user check if their session has timed out and do an ASP Abandon session to emulate exactly what would happen if their session timed out normally.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_abandon.asp